# Emacs limits number of characters pasted from system clipboard?

Tags: macos, emacs, clipboard, copy-paste

I'm running GNU Emacs 23.1.1 on Mac OS X 10.5.8.

If I copy a long string of text into system clipboard (with cmd+c) and paste it into emacs (with cmd+v) only the first 4095 (2^12) characters are pasted.

It's not a terminal quirk, as I tried it on both iTerm and standard mac term with identical results. And if I try this in vim paste works as expected. So it must be an emacs issue.

Is there a variable like max-sys-clipboard-size that I can increase so emacs will paste the the copied text in its entirety?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue using paste from a tmux paste-buffer. I was using emacs 23.2 (latest stable) on linux.

To resolve it, I upgraded to the latest development version using trunk of the bazaar repository. Under emacs 24.0.50.1, this appears to longer be a problem.

For the record, I don't believe there is a max clipboard paste limit within emacs and I think it must have been a bug of some sort.

Comment: whitman: You may wish to try the latest stable OSX version before switching to a dev release: http://emacsformacosx.com/